# Compiling and Running C++ scripts in ROS Indigo

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have written three C++ codes for one server and two clients using C++. Now I want to compile and run these scripts in ROS. I have the beginner_tutorials package as created in the tutorial. I have kept those scripts in the src directory under beginner_tutorials. But after doing catkin_make it is not getting compiled. Moreover, I have to provide command-line arguments while running those programs. I am not sure how to do that also. If anyone can help me with the steps to do it in Ubuntu 14.04.
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254192/compiling-and-running-c++-scripts-in-ros-indigo/) by [user_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28458/user_123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There should be plenty of examples on the wiki. Also, it helps if you are familiar with CMake, as you need to adapt the `CMakeLists.txt`.

Below a list of links that should answer all your questions:

- http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/index.html
- http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/BuildingPackages
- http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt

Passing in command line arguments is done just like for any other C++ program.
This also works with `rosrun`

`rosrun my_package my_node my_arg1 ...`

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [user_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28458/user_123/) on 2017-02-10**:
Thank you,I have gone through the tutorial once more and edited the CMakeLists.txt. It is working fine with rosrun now.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please go over [ROS beginner tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) starting from scratch.

Especially, [Creating a ROS Package](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage) and [Building a ROS Package](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/BuildingPackages) parts will help. You need to set your `CMakeLists.txt` file to build properly.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2017-02-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [user_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28458/user_123/) on 2017-02-10**:
Thank you,I have gone through the tutorial once more and edited the CMakeLists.txt. It is working fine with rosrun now.